# Count number of times a word appears

Tags: sas

I'm looking for a better way in SAS to count the number of times a certain word appears in a string.  Example, searching for 'wood' in the string:

```
how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood
```

... would return a result of `2`.

This is how I would normally do it but it's a lot of code:

```
data _null_;
  length sentence word $200;

  sentence = 'how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood';
  search_term = 'wood';
  found_count = 0;

  cnt=1;
  word = scan(sentence,cnt);
  do while (word ne '');
    num_times_found = sum(num_times_found, word eq search_term);
    cnt = cnt + 1;
    word = scan(sentence,cnt);
  end;

  put num_times_found=;

run;
```

I can put this into an `fcmp` function to make it more elegant but I still feel like there must be friendlier and more concise code for this.

Comment: I posted this here instead of on codereview as I didn't think that codereview would have any SAS audience.

Comment: Isn't that what countW does?

Comment: @data_null_ No - that was my first thought too, but `countw()` just counts the total number of words, not the number of times a specific word appears.

Comment: Oh! Duh.  How about FINDW instead of scanning each word.  Move the start column at each hit until it return 0 while keeping count like your doing now.  Same but different with fewer iterations.

Comment: [CodeReview.se] has a limited SAS audience, indeed; I'd actually love to have SAS questions show up there such that it would be worth my time to check the site...  That said, I think this question belongs here.  Code Review is more for bigger things - i.e., complete pieces of code, not just one function, asking about things like structure and design - though it's probably technically on topic there.

Comment: (and by that I mean, there is [*one* SAS question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79952/quicksort-in-sas-for-sorting-datasets), ever, on it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Code Review standpoint, the above can be improved somewhat.  The do loop can handle the `cnt` increment, and if you switch it to `until` you don't even have to do the initial assignment.  You also have an extraneous variable `found_count`, not sure what that is.  Otherwise, this is reasonable I think, at least for non-convoluted solutions.

```
data _null_;
  length sentence word $200;

  sentence = 'how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood';
  search_term = 'wood';

  do cnt=1 by 1 until (word eq '');
    word = scan(sentence,cnt);
    num_times_found = sum(num_times_found, word eq search_term);
  end;

  put num_times_found=;

run;
```

It's also pretty fast - 1e6 iterations takes under 9 seconds on my box.  The PRX solution when `o` is added to the string options takes less (6 seconds), so might be preferable when using very large datasets or large number of variables, but I doubt the added time will be significant compared to i/o time.  The FCMP solution takes on the same order of time as this solution (both around 8-9 seconds).  Finally, the FINDW solution is the fastest, at about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

And for completeness, here it is as an fcmp function:

**FCMP definition:**

```
options cmplib=work.temp.temp;

proc fcmp outlib=work.temp.temp;

  function word_freq(sentence $, search_term $) ;    
    length sentence word $200;

    do cnt=1 by 1 until (word eq '');
      word = scan(sentence,cnt);
      num_times_found = sum(num_times_found, word eq search_term);
    end;

    return (num_times_found);
  endsub;

run;
```

**Usage:**

```
data _null_;
  num_times_found = word_freq('how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood','wood');
  put num_times_found=;
run;
```

**Results:**

```
num_times_found=2
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to scan all the words when FINDW will effectively scan for you.

```
33         data _null_;
34            length sentence search_term $200;
35            sentence = 'how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood';
36            search_term = 'wood';
37            cnt=0;
38            do s=findw(sentence,strip(search_term),1) by 0 while(s);
39               cnt+1;
40               s=findw(sentence,strip(search_term),s+1);
41               end;
42            put cnt= search_term=;
43            stop;
44            run;

cnt=2 search_term=wood
```

Comment: Definitely faster than the SCAN method by quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try to drop wood with prxchange, then countw.

```
data _null_;
sentence = 'how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood';
count=countw(sentence,' ')-countw(prxchange('s/wood/$1/i',-1,sentence),' ');
put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: Technically this translates `woodchuck` into `chuck` of course, but that doesn't affect the result.

Comment: And - this is what I was referring to by 'convoluted solutions' - not because it's wrong, but it's not as straightforward, and might be avoided based on that principle (as it'll be harder for others to see what you're doing).

Comment: You might add the `o` option to your prx, otherwise it takes quite a long time to run multiple iterations.

Comment: Nice approach.  This solution wins the 'most concise' award, but I have to agree with Joe that it isn't as 'friendly' so I'm going to mark his as the accepted answer.